# Can't Access AKS Cluster in second Terraform Cloud Run

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm using the following script to manage an AKS cluster and Helm chart.
It ran the first time, but on subsequent runs it can't access the cluster. I've added a 'depends_on' but it hasn't helped.

The error I get is:

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: invalid configuration: no configuration has 
been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable
with helm_release.nginx
on kubernetes.tf line 38, in resource "helm_release" "nginx":
```

The Terraform  Cloud script is:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "Example_Test" {
  name                = "Cluster_Example_Test"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "Example_Test"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Development"
  }
}

data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "Example_Test" {
  name                = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.Example_Test.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.Example_Test.resource_group_name
  depends_on          = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.Example_Test]
}

provider "helm" {

  kubernetes {
    host                   = 
data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.Example_Test.kube_config.0.host
    client_certificate     = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.Example_Test.kube_config.0.client_certificate)
    client_key             = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.Example_Test.kube_config.0.client_key)
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.Example_Test.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "nginx" {
  name       = "nginx"
  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart      = "ingress-nginx"
  provider = helm
  set {
    name  = "controller.replicaCount"
    value = "1"
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.Example_Test]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: invalid configuration: no configuration.

There might be chance of unavailability of the Kubernetes cluster configuration when terraform runs subsequent times. It's important to ensure that the cluster configuration is available before executing the `Helm chart` deployment.

I have followed below terraform code to create `AKS Cluster` with `Helm` chart.

```
   provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks-rg2" {
  name     = "xxxx-resources1"
  location = "West Europe"
}
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster2" {
  name                = "my-aks-demo"
  location            = "westus2"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks-rg2.name
  dns_prefix          = "myakscluster"
  
  default_node_pool {
    name                = "default"
    node_count          = 1
    vm_size             = "Standard_DS2_v2"
    type                = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    enable_auto_scaling = true
    min_count           = 1
    max_count           = 3
  }
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
  }
}
data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "venakt_Test" {
  name                = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster2.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster2.resource_group_name
  depends_on          = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster2]
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.venakt_Test.kube_config.0.host
    client_certificate     = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.venakt_Test.kube_config.0.client_certificate)
    client_key             = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.venakt_Test.kube_config.0.client_key)
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.venakt_Test.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate) 
    load_config_file       = false
  }
} 
resource "helm_release" "my_helm_chart" {
  name       = "my-helm-chart"
  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/"
  chart      = "ingress-nginx"
  depends_on = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster2]
set {
    name  = "replicaCount"
    value = "3"
  }
set {
    name  = "image.tag"
    value = "v1.2.3"
  }
set {
    name  = "app.port"
    value = "8080"
  }
}
```

```
Note: Remove the `provider = helm` argument from the `helm_release` resource since it is already specified in the `provider "helm"` block, and having it in both places would result in duplicate providers**
```

**Terraform apply**

[image]

Refer [Kubernetes cluster unreachable invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/1234#top) for more details.